# django admin site showing with out format

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django test site and I can see the admin site, but it has different formatting from the tutorial examples.

This is how my admin site looks:

[image]

But on the example it looks like this:

[image]

What is missing to show the correct formatting?

Comment: Why the down votes? Is this obvious?

Comment: A little, yes. And, it's covered in the docs. And, there's a dozen or so similar questions here already on StackOverflow. The downvotes are likely for lack of research. See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Comment: @ChrisPratt, ok thanks, I just was in a big doubt as if the framework generated automatically the CSS, I have followed a lot of hello world examples and read a lot to have the django installed in the server, and all, haha, but in none of the examples of research I saw a reference to the CSS.. thanks! I dont mind being downvoted as long as my problems gets solved! ;)

Comment: Well of course the goal is to write a thorough and detailed question that shows you've taken initiative, and then get your problem solved. You'll likely get upvoted instead of downvoted then. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your CSS file isn't being loaded. Make sure your django install is set up correctly to server out static files. The CSS file, by default, is in `/static/admin/css`.

Answer (score 1):

uncomment 'django.contrib.staticfiles' under INSTALLED_APPS from settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

One cause of the admin page being in the wrong format is disabling debug mode.

What is missing to show the correct formatting, as zigdon writes, is stylesheet (CSS) files. Stylesheet, javascript and image files are examples of *static files* and these must be *served* to the django app.

As explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/), disabling debug mode will also disable serving the basic static files using django.contrib.staticfiles, resulting in bad format. Setting
`DEBUG = True` in settings.py will then correct the admin page format.

This solution is of course only useful during development, before releasing the project to its end users. As a released (production mode) project, the django app should no longer serve the static files it uses. As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/), the static files could instead be served using a web server like Apache.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34535332)

Comment: I have improved the answer. Hopefully it is useful to new django programmers. For instance, following [the w3schools django tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/django/index.php) can result in a bad admin page format if the debug setting in the step "Django 404 Template" is not reverted.